# API for Inbox by Gmail

Tags: gmail-api

Is there any talk of when there will be an API for the new Inbox by Gmail.  We would like to integrate into it and would specifically like to tie into the Reminders and Snoozes.

Answer (score 3):

Google as a rule does not talk about potential features or release dates. To get informed if a Inbox API is ever released you should subscribe to the [Google Developers blog](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/) or the [Gmail blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/).

And just as a note the email content of Inbox is already available through the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).