# Accessing Google Inbox reminders using API

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Is there any way to access [Google Inbox](http://www.google.com/inbox/) reminders via [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) or another way? I know that Google Inbox can show reminders from Google Keep, but can't find any information about how this communication is done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot get the reminders via the Gmail API at this time.

[Google Keep, Now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728176/is-there-a-public-google-api-to-access-reminders-set-in-google-now-or-google-kee) and [Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528778/api-for-inbox-by-gmail) have no APIs either sadly.

So if you are making an application, your cannot get the reminders of your users as of yet.

To get your own reminders though, simply type "What are my reminders?" into Google.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I wanted to show JIRA issues with due date in Google Inbox as reminders, but unfortunatelly it's not possible yet.

Comment: @Kartik I don't think so. I have not heard of any new API, and a quick Google search on all the APIs revealed nothing.

Comment: This is so sad (from a walled garden perspective) and annoying (from a power user perspective).  :-/

Answer (score 3):

It seems that reminders have been integrated into the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders), although I'm not sure whether these are the same kind of reminders.

Comment: "Reminders are alarms triggered at a specified time before an event starts". I think these are the calendar event specific reminders, sadly. Not the Google Inbox reminders OP was asking for.

Comment: Calendar has integrated the Reminders API, that is provided by GooglePlayServices using a unnoficial (or unreleased) API. Unfortunatelly, only Keep, Inbox, Now and Calendar developers know this API. Google is closing their source code to other developers like Apple :(

Comment: Given the last news about Google Inbox dead in next March my guess is that Google will offer some migration path for Inbox Reminders. Maybe through an API, maybe through an export option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Google Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/) that is available which has some reminder functionality built into GMail.

Comparrison of Google Keep, Google Inbox Reminders and Google Tasks as well as info found at [The Google Tasks Guide: How to Get the Most Out of the Simplest To-Do App](https://zapier.com/blog/google-tasks-guide/)